# INSERT auto_increment value

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with a few values and a primary key that is auto_incremented from 1:

```
create table test1 (acounter int not null primary key, studentid int not null, 
ranking int not null, aweek date not null);

alter table test1 auto_increment=1;
```

If I were able to I could `INSERT INTO test1 (NULL,1012,1,'2015-04-20')`, but the data comes in a different order so I tried `INSERT INTO test1 (acounter,aweek,ranking,studentid) VALUES (NULL,'2015-04-20',1,1012)` - receive an error that the primary key cannot be NULL. I don't want it to be - I expect the auto_increment to use the next value.

Comment: Don't provide the autoincrement field name or a value for it in the statement. Pretend its not there and the DB will take care of it.

Comment: You dont want to insert into an auto increment values

Comment: INSERT INTO test1 (aweek,ranking,studentid) VALUES ('2015-04-20',1,1012)

Answer (score 1):

When you declared a column as auto increment ,Db will take of it as you insert the other values to the table.

```
INSERT INTO test1 (aweek,ranking,studentid) VALUES
 ('2015-04-20',1,1012)
```